# Is it possible to perform a SELECT and an UPDATE in a single SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite

I might not be wording the title properly but I'm wondering if it's possible to both read data and update data in a single query (or multiple queries in a single *call*?) using SQLite.

As an example situation I would like to `SELECT` the current state of the database then `UPDATE` the state to something new all in one single atomic query.

Here is how I'm pulling this off using Postgres:

```sql
UPDATE migrations_lock
SET is_locked = 0
WHERE index = 1 RETURNING (
  SELECT is_locked AS was_locked
  FROM migrations_lock
  WHERE index = 1
);
```

Likewise, I'm able to achieve the same thing in MySQL using a transaction:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT is_locked AS was_locked
      FROM migrations_lock
      WHERE `index` = 1;
    UPDATE migrations_lock
      SET is_locked = 0
      WHERE `index` = 1;
COMMIT;
```

Sadly, running the same Postgres query in SQLite returns the new data instead of the existing data. Running the equivalent MySQL query in SQLite form (`BEGIN TRANSACTION`) returns an error about nested transactions. Running the `SELECT` followed by the `UPDATE` query in a single call (without the transaction) results in the `SELECT` query running and the `UPDATE` query being ignored.

There is some additional context about how the query is being run [in this pull request](https://github.com/tlhunter/mig/pull/3/files#diff-38bf61338ee8a736cf35b18853286207ad4a6729ff6b7e021b7a454ae097414fR21-R30).

Comment: If you have nested transaction, why don't you just not start a new nested one ?

Comment: @davidriod That's the last thing I tried "Running the SELECT followed by the UPDATE query in a single call (without the transaction) results in the SELECT query running and the UPDATE query being ignored."

Comment: What makes you think the update is ignored ? What are the symptoms ? Because clearly it won't, it's a regular use case so you probably have something wrong in your where clause.

Comment: @davidriod in DBeaver, if I highlight those two queries, the first being SELECT and the second the UPDATE for is_locked=0, and I press Ctrl+Enter, the data returned contains is_locked=1. This is correct assuming is_locked was 1 going in. If I press Ctrl+Enter again, the value is still returned as 1, proving the UPDATE didn't work. SELECT-ing the data by other means also shows the update didn't work. Using MySQL and PostgreSQL, both selected queries are run. Based on this conversation https://sqlite.org/forum/info/2a9775b88a90d2e6 it looks like SQlite doesn't really support multiple queries.

Comment: Thomas what's your target programming environment ? I've tried a few things with the sqlite3 command and with a go test program. And it exhibits different behaviours. From sqlite3, everything works like a charm. But from the go test program, I have something different. Actually the update works, but I don't retrieve any value. The easiest solution for you would be to split your SQL statement, if it's possible.

Comment: @davidriod I'm also using Go as well, specifically the mattn/go-sqlite3 package. I'm seeing the same thing you mentioned where the SELECT doesn't seem to return data and the UPDATE runs. My guess is that all queries are firing but it's just not expecting to return data. I'll file an issue with that repo.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite since version 3.33.0 supports UPDATE FROM see

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html#update_from

Another possibility is to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to drive an UPDATE as per

> All common table expressions (ordinary and recursive) are created by prepending a WITH clause in front of a SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement. A single WITH clause can specify one or more common table expressions, some of which are ordinary and some of which are recursive.

- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

An example of using a CTE to drive an update:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (datee TEXT, other_colmumns);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
    ,('not the date I wanted','otherdate')
;
SELECT rowid,* FROM test; /* result 1 prior to update */

/* The CTE driven UPDATE */
WITH x AS (SELECT rowid FROM test LIMIT 10,5)
    UPDATE test SET datee = '19/12/2021' WHERE test.rowid IN (SELECT * FROM x)
;
SELECT rowid,* FROM test; /* result 2 after update */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test; /* clean up */
```

- Result 1 being

  - [image]
- Result 2 being

  - [image]

Modifying the CTE for multiple selects (2 ctes x and y):-

```
/* The CTE driven UPDATE */
WITH x AS (SELECT rowid FROM test LIMIT 10,5),
     y as (SELECT rowid FROM test LIMIT 1,2)
    UPDATE test SET datee = '19/12/2021' WHERE test.rowid IN (SELECT * FROM x UNION ALL SELECT * FROM y)
;
```

- result 2 is then

  - [image]

Comment: The `UPDATE FROM` and CTE approaches you provided like they're used to update data based on existing data. But in my case I'm looking to atomically read an old value and set a new value in a single database call, and the UPDATE query that I'm using doesn't depend on any existing data.